# Working with exponentiation number in php

Tags: php, math, exponentiation

I have this number: 1.8112336829e+01

I get it from xml file with function simplexml_load

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
$number = $xml->data->row->v[1]; // assign number with the value 1.8112336829e+01
echo $number * 8; // outputs 1.
```

I want to multiply this by 8. 
On calculator: 1.8112336829 * 10^1 * 8 = 144.898694632

How can I format this the correct way with PHP to receive the right answer?

Comment: You mean, your PHP-Script has "1.8112336829e+01" as input and should output "144.898694632"?

Comment: Yes, i edited my question so it's more understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This works just like you said...

```
$number = 1.8112336829e+01;
echo $number * 8;
```

## Edit

Maybe `$number` is an Object. Try to cast.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root><data><row><v>2</v><v>1.8112336829e+01</v></row></data></root>');

$number = $xml->data->row->v[1];
echo $number * 8; // outputs 8
echo (float)$number * 8; // outputs 144.898694632
```

Comment: This outputs 8. PHP only multiplying (1*8).

Comment: Maybe you want to share your code and we can see what you are doing wrong

Comment: Sorry Berriel, I should have tested your code.
This is what I do:
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
    $number = $xml->data->row->v[1];
    echo $number * 8;
From data.xml I get value 1.8112336829e+01 with $xml->data->row->v[1] where v[1] is the value. It seems this is not working when I get the value from xml?

Comment: See my edit. If it doesn't work, show the `var_dump($number)`

Comment: Thats it! It was an Object. (float) was the way to go, thanks Berriel!